# Error opening ports in C++ to Arduino in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, arduino

I am programming in ARduino and I am try to connect Arduino with C++. I have the folowing function:

```
//Prueba.cpp
#include <iostream>  
#include <SerialStream.h>
#include "/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0"

using namespace std;  
using namespace LibSerial;

int main() {
SerialStream my_serial_stream;
my_serial_stream.Open("/dev/ttyACM0");
my_serial_stream.SetBaudRate(SerialStreamBuf::BAUD_9600);
my_serial_stream << "a0" << endl; 
return 0;
}
```

But when I exeute it, give me a lot of error with like this.

```
usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\377’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\17’ parásito en el programa   
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\37’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\200’ parásito en el programa
In file included from Prueba.cpp:11:0:
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:914: aviso: caracter(es) nulo(s) ignorados         [activado por defecto]
In file included from Prueba.cpp:11:0:
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\205’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\355’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\17’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\204’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\351’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\376’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\377’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\377’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\277’ parásito en el programa
/usr/local/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0:99:1: error: ‘\20’ parásito en el programa
```

Anyone know hay this happend? I installed libserial with sudo apt-get install libserdial-dev but nothing.

Comment: you should translate what "parasite en el programa" means

Comment: You are including `.so`?

Comment: I would suggest to use termio to connect to Arduino from Linux. It is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that this might help you in general: [this](http://sglez.org/2008/08/05/interfacing-arduino-with-c-and-libserial/)

Comment: It not works. It fail in the includes and later, in the namespace Libserial.

Comment: `parasito en el programa` means a bug in program?